# Printing HTML tags without escaping using EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am using EJS with Node JS. Also I am using i18n-node-2 for multilingual site.
In my view I have a statement like this:

```
<h3 class="panel-title"><%= i18n.__("Business Card maker wizard - Step %s", "<span id='bcMakerStep'>1</span>") %></h3>
```

Here I want to output`<span id='bcMakerStep'>1</span>` as it is.
But the EJS is transforming it into Business Card maker wizard - Step <span id='bcMakerStep'>1</span> so that is displaying as it is.

Is there any way in EJS to print the tags as it is?

PS: I have tested without EJS to check whether i18n-node-2 is doing that, but it is not but EJS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render a variable as HTML in EJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326950/render-a-variable-as-html-in-ejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the answer,

If we use <%- instead of <%= it will print characters unescaped.

Thanks to Jakub Oboza at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330401/721597