# What does <% and %> mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for asking here. I tried googling it with no luck. 
I found it in chartjs's core script.

Example(actual code snippet):

```
// String - Template string for single tooltips
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>",
```

Link: 
https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js

Do a `ctrl+f` for `<%` and you will see many of them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a templating system

Comment: Example: [Render a variable as HTML in EJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326950/render-a-variable-as-html-in-ejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [Line 46](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js#L465) you can see in the comments it mentions they're using this [Mirco-Templating language](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

Answer (score 0):

Its a [templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) system. For example :

```
<script type="text/html" id="item_tmpl">
  <div id="<%=id%>" class="<%=(i % 2 == 1 ? " even" : "")%>">
    <div class="grid_1 alpha right">
      <img class="righted" src="<%=profile_image_url%>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6 omega contents">
      <p><b><a href="/<%=from_user%>"><%=from_user%></a>:</b> <%=text%></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```