# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with server variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following line of code produces the title error:

```
  var tweets = <%= tweets %>;
```

In the chrome console it is displayed as the following:

```
var tweets = [object Object];
```

Why is this error being thrown? From similar questions it seems to be an issue of syntax but I am unsure how the above syntax can be changed?

I was initally stringifying the object before sending but this presented errors with unexpected characters being found.

Comment: run this script console.log(<%= tweets %>); to check input data.

Comment: it is displayed as [object Object];

Answer (score 0):

You get `[object Object]` when you convert an object to a string, which is what's happening with your templating system.

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  stuff: 'things'
};
document.write(obj);
```

You can create a comparable object by printing out the JSON representation of that object:

```
var tweets = <%- JSON.stringify(tweets) %>;
//             ^-- Change to - instead of = to avoid escaping
```

This works because JSON is a subset of JavaScript and can therefore be used directly within JavaScript to create objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response, stringifying the variable now raises the error I mentioned which is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &, because the quotation marks are being represented as &#34

Comment: @user4357505 Then that all depends on what you're using to print it out. That's going to be responsible for how it handles printing text.

Comment: @Mike_C I'm unsure what you mean? the error is raised on the line that the variable is declared as you have stated in your answer

Comment: @user4357505 Whatever you're using to use that `<%= %>` syntax is formatting your data so it can be presented as HTML. To fix this problem, you need to change that so it produces the raw data. I don't know what you're using so I can't tell you how to fix that part.

Comment: Ah okay I see, I am using express routing to send the variable. 'res.render('index.html', {tweets: tweetobj};' Does it need to be handle before sending?

Comment: @user4357505 You could perform the `JSON.stringify(tweetobj)` before sending it. That is probably what you need.

Comment: @user4357505 Then it all depends on what template engine you're using. What template engine are you using to render your stuff from Express?

Comment: The engine is rendered with ejs, app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

Comment: @user4357505 Change `<%=` to `<%-`. Then the code [won't be escaped.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326950/render-a-variable-as-html-in-ejs)