# when express use view engine, pass a html string,how to make it render to html

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want to imitate `jekyll`,build a blog with nodejs and express; I use the `fs` module read the `markdown` file and translate into html string;then I use `res.render('view',{html:html})` to pass my html string ,but in the end it render as text,how can I do? render it into html..

```
router.get('/:year/:month/:day/:title', function (req, res) {

var fileName = 
'../blogs/' +
req.params.year + '-' + 
req.params.month + '-' + 
req.params.day + '-' + 
req.params.title + '.md';
  fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8',function (err, data) {
       if (err) res.send(err);
        h=md2html.toHTML(data);
        console.log(h);
        res.render('blog',{h:h});
  });
 });
```

blog.ejs:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>lla</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
 </head>
 <body>
 <%=h%>
 </body>
 <html>
```

the result:
[image]

Comment: where is view.html file?

Comment: already add the .ejs file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render a variable as HTML in EJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326950/render-a-variable-as-html-in-ejs)

Comment: thanks,it solved out!