# html tags being rendered instead of the values

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am trying to render a saved Rich Text from my Mongodb database to an ejs page. The ejs for the unrendered part is like this :

```
<div> <%= description %> </div>
```

Because it's a rich text,my html tags are saved a long with the values in my db.Now when i try to render that to my page i get the whole thing as a string tags rather than getting a rendered value.

[image]

as you can see the rest of the page is rendering fine except my saved rich text.

any help is appreciated.

thx

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the
shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other 
readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This might help you. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330401/465560. You should use unescaped tag `<%- richtext -%>` instead of `<%= richtext =%>`.

Comment: Thanks a million @Priya , solved the problem right a way.

Comment: You are welcome. As said by @NeilLunn please give atleast input or description like you are using `ejs` so that next time a fella comes to your post should feel helpful with the question and answer.

Comment: Duly noted ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ejs` use

`<%- YOUR_HTML_CONTENT %>` which will render HTML content

Comment: Thx a lot Muthu!