# Render a variable as HTML in Java Spring Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

In my .java file, I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String callback(@RequestParam(name = "token") String token, Model model){
    //do something with token
    //result variable is either 
    //"<p style=\"color:red;font-size:20px\"><strong>fail</strong></p>" 
    //or 
    //"<p style=\"color:green;font-size:20px\"><strong>pass</strong></p>"
    model.addAttribute("result", result);
    return "page1";
```

in my page1.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Page1</title>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'here is the result: ' + ${result}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, my page1 displays:

```
here is the result: <p style="color:green;font-size:20px"><strong>pass</strong></p>
```

Is it possible to render my result variable as html so that my page1 displays a big green pass? Are there other formatting options rather than th:text + ${var}?I'm using spring boot and thymeleaf. I'm trying not to use javascript for this.

Something like this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326950/render-a-variable-as-html-in-ejs), but for java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this one:

```
th:utext="'here is the result: ' + ${result}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad mixture of presentation and semantics at the controller level, and a bad mixture of content and style at the HTML level. Instead, use a boolean attribute for `result` and use `th:if` or similar to switch the HTML content in your template, and avoid inline styles in favor of something like `class="success"`.