# node js render post data and raw html

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started to learn node.js today and I'm trying to render post data and raw html using EJS template engine.

I am trying to render the post data and raw html depending on the if else if statement in stats.

I'm not sure if this could be done so i was hoping maybe someone could tell me if it can be?

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {  
  res.render(__dirname + "/views/index");
});

app.post('/stats', (req, res) => {
  var first_name = req.body.firstname;
  var last_name = req.body.lastname;
  
  if (!first_name) {
    var html_code = "<b>You didn't add a first name</b>";
    
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/stats", {
      htmlcode: html_code
    });
    
  } else if (!last_name) {
    var html_code = "<b>You didn't add a last name</b>";
    
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/stats", {
      htmlcode: html_code
    });
    
  } else if (first_name && last_name) {
    var html_code = "<b>First name is </b><%= first_name %> <br> <b>Last name is </b><%= last_name %>";
    
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/stats", {
      htmlcode: html_code,
      firstname: first_name,
      lastname: last_name
    });
    
  } 
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

views/index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Send Stats</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://server.com/stats" method="POST">
      firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br/>
      lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br/>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

views/stats.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>name stats</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><%= htmlcode %></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

output:

```
<b>First name is </b><%= first_name %> <br> <b>Last name is </b><%= last_name %>
```

Comment: It looks fine. Have you tested the server yet?

Comment: Yeah i have tested it on a server and the output above is what i see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var html_code = "<b>First name is </b><%= first_name %> <br> <b>Last name is </b><%= last_name %>";
```

To

```
var html_code = `<b>First name is </b>${first_name} <br> <b>Last name is </b>${last_name}`;
```

## Update

You can either usr `<%-` instead of `<%=`, which will not escapes the characters, but will make the code vulnerable to [code injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Code_Injection). Instead, pass the variables to the template by changing `views/stats.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>name stats</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><b>First name is </b><%= first_name %> <br> <b>Last name is </b><%= last_name %></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To learn more, read about [string literals in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Oh thanks! But the output now looks like:

<b>First name is </b>John <br> <b>Last name is </b>Doe

I still see the html <b> tags?

Comment: Using `<%=` escapes the characters, so the browser sees &gt. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330401/1231844. `<%-` Doesn't escape… although this is often not a good idea.