# I want to print the data from the database into the element with ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

[this is my data on database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n0o9.png)

and this is my posts.ejs file

```
<p>
    <%= data[i]['article'] %>
</p>
```

[and this is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWrcH.png)

how can i write it in pre tag

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330401/5347939) answer your question?

Comment: @zhisme yeah it is. thanks. i solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

`<%- data[i]['article'] %>`

Instead of this

`<%= data[i]['article'] %>`

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51924757/10980464)

Comment: @AbdiKaan - great