# How to store HTML emoji v3.0 code in PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, ejs, postgresql-12

I would like to store a couple of country flags into my PostgreSQL database. But when my website's view file fetches the flag data the **source output** looks like this text `<td>&amp;#127482;&amp;#127480;</td>` and not the **flag Emoji**.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (country, flag) VALUES ('United States', '&#127482;&#127480;');
```

I tried to create the flag column with these Data Types:

- VARCHAR(150)
- TEXT

But the web browser's source output doesn't seem to give me the visual Emoji. I DuckDuckGo some websites and PostgreSQL docs, and read some other threads on this issue. But I can't grasp their answers and understand how to implement this.

Help please.

It works when I hard code the Emojis directly into my HTML files but not when I save it to Postgres and fetches it with EJS.

https://www.quackit.com/character_sets/emoji/emoji_v3.0/emoji_icons_flags.cfm

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp

Comment: I suspect this is ejs escaping the string.  Assuming you have the html string in a variable, the correct template syntax for you might be ```<%- your_variable %>``` as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326950/render-a-variable-as-html-in-ejs  I think Postgres has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @BjarniRagnarsson you are correct I just took a look at Tags chapter and tried it out.
https://ejs.co/

Before = Incorrect,
`<%= your_variable %>`

After = Correct,
`<%- your_variable %>`

But it seems I only get the visual Emoji as intended on Firefox not in Chrome. Guess I have to resort to using image files for my flags in order to display it correctly on all web browsers.