# Printing newline characters in ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'd like to print a string with newline characters with ejs.

I have this ejs file:

```
<div class="result">
  <%=names%>
</div>
```

If the string "names" is "line 1</br>line 2" it will print it literally:

```
line 1</br>line 2
```

But I'd like this:

```
line 1
line 2
```

What is the best way of getting ejs to correctly interpret newline characters?

Comment: you need HTML unescaped syntax <%-names%> follow this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330401/7887883

Answer (score 3):

The ejs syntax I was using is specifically for unescaped input:

```
<div class="result">
  <%=names%>
</div>
```

Simply using '-' instead of '=' gives the desired result:

```
<div class="result">
  <%-names%>
</div>
```

Which gives:

```
line 1
line 2
```

Kudos @Pavan Kumar T S